# keeping localStorage objects that iterate whilst using clear() within the same function

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I'm trying to clear all local storage when the user either completes the game loop or starts a new game, but also keep some values.

I can do this already with my sound values for volume:

```
// inside a conditional statement that fires when the user chooses to start a new game.
if (newGameBool === '1') {
    var tst = myAu;
//myAu is the stored value that the user sets as sound using a range type input

    localStorage.clear();

    localStorage.setItem("Au", tst);//A newly cleared localStorage just got a new value, and it's the same as it was before. 

    UI.myLoad();//reload the function that uses LS to do things. 

}
```

How do I do this for key's that have an iterating number attached to them?

Here is how I save them:

```
var i = +v + +1; 

localStorage.setItem("v", i);

var vv = localStorage.getItem("v");

localStorage.setItem("LdrBrd_" + vv, JSON.stringify(LdrBrd));//saves all data with the iterating key name.
```

Calling them the way i did the sound function:

```
var gv = v + 1;//v calls the value from LS and adjusted for off-by-one error.  gv is a local variable.
if (newGameBool === '1') {
    var ldd, vg;

    for (var ii = 0; ii < gv; ii++) {
        var ld = localStorage.getItem("LdrBrd_" + ii);
        if (ld != null) {
        //these are the values that i want to pass beyond the clear point
            ldd = JSON.parse(ld);//JSON string of data saved
            vg = ii;//how many of them.
        }

    }

    localStorage.clear();

    for (var xx = 0; xx < vg; xx++) {
        var nld = localStorage.getItem("LdrBrd_" + xx);
        if (nld != null) {
           localStorage.setItem("LdrBrd_" + ii, JSON.stringify(ldd));
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem("v", vg);

    UI.myLoad();

}
```

I have been using console.log() in various spots to see what is going on.  I comment-out the clear function just to see if the values were wrong and they don't save all all.  I tried to make a fiddle, but the local storage wasn't working at all there.  In visual studio, it works fine but the script to this file is almost 2000 lines long, so i tried to dress it up the best i knew how.

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

Comment: Why are you clearing it entirely if you want to keep some data instead of just removing the data you want to remove?

Comment: because i want to clear everything else, there are about 20 or so items that i want to remove and only a few i want to keep and pass on to the gamestate beyond the clear point

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this for a few days, but i think i found something that will work, so i'll answer my own question in case there is value in posterity.

```
locatStorage.clear();
/*  ^LS clear() function is above all new setItem codes, some variables are declared globally and some are declared at the top of the functional scope or as param^  */
var itemClass = document.querySelectorAll(".itemClass");//the strings are here

if (itemClass) {//make sure some exist
    for (var p = 0; p < itemClass.length; p++) {//count them
        mdd = JSON.parse(itemClass[p].innerText);//parse the data for saving

        localStorage.setItem("v", v);//this is the LS item that saves the amount of items i have, it's declared at the top of the functions timeline.
        localStorage.setItem("LdrBrd_" + p, JSON.stringify(mdd));//this setItem function will repeat and increment with 'p' and assign the right string back to the key name it had before.
    }
}
```

The key is to keep the strings physically attached to an element, then call the class name. The i ran a loop counting them.  'mdd' will spit back each item i want.  So then all that is left to do is re-set the item back to it's original status.

This has allowed me to create a way for my users to collect trophies and keep them even after clearing the localStorage when the he/she decides to start a new game.

I use CSS to hide the text from the string.

```
color:transparent;
```

In my gameLoop, i have a function that will read the saved strings and show them as cards just below the hidden strings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to keep some values I recommend one of two things:

1. Don't call `localStorage.clear()` and instead only wipe out the values that you want using `localStorage.removeItem('itemName')`.  Since you said the item names have a numeric component, maybe you can do this in a loop to reduce code.
2. Pull item(s) that you want saved first and restore them after calling `clear()`.  This option is best if there are way more items that you want removed rather than saved (see below)

```
function mostlyClear() {
    var saveMe = {};
    saveMe['value1'] = localStorage.getItem('value1');
    saveMe['anotherValue'] = localStorage.getItem('anotherValue');
    localStorage.clear();
    for(var prop in saveMe) {
        if(!saveMe.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

        localStorage.setItem(prop, saveMe[prop]);
    }
}
```